# Is it possible to set TortoiseGit stash name from the command line?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-stash

Is there a way to specify a name for the stash when using the command line tool?

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:stashsave
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with TortoiseGit 1.8.10.0 you can use

```
TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:stashsave /msg:"MSG"
```

See [Revision: 74352b9ed427](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/commit/74352b9ed427d32dba89472b62f583a9049fce4e).

For older version you have to use `git.exe`as a fallback:

```
git stash save "message"
```

Comment: I know that is possible, but i want to show the TortoiseGit GUI and pre-fill a stash name. Trying to make git as user friendly as possible ;)

Comment: *`git stash save "message"`

Comment: @Biffen thanks; sboulema: please report feature requests to https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/list, if the TortoiseGit developers don't know them, they can't implement them